# Changing Bootstrap panel CSS class for "active" panel (clicked/focused)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatables, focus

I have a page with multiple Bootstrap panels, and I want to make it so that only the "active" panel has the `panel-primary` class (so, highlighted, in a sense). The definition of "active" in this case is that the user has clicked anywhere inside a panel or changed focus with keyboard or something.

So, I started with this:

```
function highlightActivePanel($activePanel) {
    $('.panel-primary').toggleClass('panel-primary panel-default');
    $activePanel.toggleClass('panel-default panel-primary');
}

$(document).on('click', '.panel-default', function () {
    highlightActivePanel($(this));
});
```

The trouble is, I have a table with jquery *DataTables* plugin inside the panels. So, if I register the `click` event, it generally works, but not when you click on of the DataTables paging number buttons at the bottom of the panel for some reason. The click even doesn't fire. Probably due to DT's own click events, I'm guessing.

So, I then tried the `focus` event:

```
$(document).on('focus', '.panel-default', function () {
    highlightActivePanel($(this));
});
```

... and that works better with clicking on DataTables buttons and fields, but doesn't work if the user simply clicks on the text (or in a table cell) inside a panel.

Finally, if I just simply leave both event listeners registered, it seems to work, but I'm wondering if this is smart, or if there is a better/cleaner way of doing this?

```
$(document).on('click', '.panel-default', function () {
    highlightActivePanel($(this));
});
$(document).on('focus', '.panel-default', function () {
    highlightActivePanel($(this));
});
```

Here's a [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xogqp8oa/4/) that better illustrates what I'm talking about.

---

Edit: Just realized I can easily combine the two events like this:

```
$(document).on('click focus', '.panel-default', function () {
    highlightActivePanel($(this));
});
```

But if there is still a better way to do this, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Clicking on the DataTables paging numbers [triggers](https://datatables.net/reference/event/) `page.dt`, so you could do `click page.dt` in place of `click focus` to avoid potentially losing focus to something else on the page (though you could also do that by using a more specific selector).

Comment: Thanks. Although, doesn't `on('click focus', '.panel-default'...` already provide enough specificity? Unless I'm misunderstanding the use, the `.panel-default` means it will only fire for `click focus` inside elements with `.panel-default` class, right?

Comment: Yes to the how it works part but no to the enough specificity - `.panel-default` is a Bootstrap class and may be found on panels that are not related to DataTables

Comment: Ah nevermind, you do want to include all the bootstrap panels. You should be fine then.